# How to handle Microsoft FTP server being DDoSed

Tags: ddos, iis, ftp, windows-server

We noticed FTP service going down intermittently in the server and we found an FTP user was used to DDoS the server. Then we deleted the specific user from the server. After that the user "anonymous" was hitting the server with 1000s of connections as seen here https://prnt.sc/JtCx7n1ok3Xv . Things we have tried so far

1. IIS manager -> FTP site -> FTP authentication and disabled anonymous authentication
2. IIS manager -> FTP site -> FTP authorization rule and added a deny rule for "All anonymous users"
3. Located the anonymous user MSFTP7_023979 and disabled it
4. Removed the user MSFTP7_023979 permission for the FTP site folder

But still getting connections from anonymous user. Is there a way to block all FTP connections from anonymous user?

Comment: *"Is there a way to block all FTP connections from anonymous user?"* - you don't know the user until it attempts authentication. That's why you cannot block it earlier. If you are sure that the user is only connecting from a specific IP address (like some runaway script trying again and again) and no other valid user is using this source IP then you could block this IP in the firewall.

Comment: If you are expecting only certain IPs to connect to the FTP server, then you can place a firewall in front and only allow those IPs through. If you can't do that, then you need to  increase your server resources to handle the increased load. If you are exposing yourself to the Internet, then you need to handle the Internet.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich the connections are from random unique IPs.
@ schroeder♦ for now we have restricted FTP port access to specific IPs. But this is not a long term solution since this is a public facing server.